# Problem while enabling CCK module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I am trying to enable CCK module and when I try to enable it, I get a white screen with this URL (http://localhost/?q=admin/build/modules/list/confirm). But CCK is not being enabled

I dont know whats wrong. This is what I am doing before trying to enable CCK.

1. I downloaded CCK, extracted it and put it in /sites/all/modules/ folder
2. Go to http://localhost
3. Go to Modules section and trying to check the check boxes corresponding CCK module.

Please tell me what can be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from here: [The White Screen of Death (Completely Blank Page)](http://drupal.org/node/158043)
One of problem may be memory limit...

Answer (score 0):

This may be The White Screen of Death. If there are some errors they can be found by adding the below code in the starting of index.php in the drupal installation.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```